# Spark integration in existing application using cassandra

Tags: csv, cassandra, apache-spark, datastax

We have working application with one application server and 3 node Cassandra cluster. Recently we got new requirement to import large CSV files to our existing database. Rows in CSV need to be transformed before saving in Cassandra. Our infrastructure is deployed in Amazon AWS.

Have couple questions:

1. It looks to us that Spark is right tool for the job since it has [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) and [Spark CSV plugin](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv). Are we correct?
2. Maybe a newbie Spark question, but in our deployment scenario where should importer app be deployed? Our idea is to have Spark Master on one of DB nodes, Spark workers spread on 3 database nodes and importer application on same node where is master. It would be perfect to have some command line interface to import CSV which can later evolve to API/web interface.
3. Can we put importer application on application server and what will be network penalty?
4. Can we use Spark in this scenario for Cassandra JOINS as well and how can we integrate to existing application which already uses regular Datastax java driver along with application joins if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind that Spark Cassandra Connector will only be useful for data locality **if you're loading your data from Cassandra, not from an external source**. So, for loading a CSV file, you'll have to transport it to your Spark workers, using a shared storage or HDFS, etc. Which means that wherever you place your importer application, it will stream the data to your spark Workers.

Now to address your points:

1. You're correct about Spark, but incorrect about Spark Cassandra Connector, as it's only useful if you're loading data from Cassandra (which might be the case for #4 when you need to perform Joins between external data and Cassandra data), otherwise it won't give you any significant help.
2. Your *importer* application will be deployed to your cluster. In the scenario you described, this is a stand-alone Spark Cluster. So you'll need to package your application, then use the **spark-submit** command on your master node to deploy your application. Using a command line parameter for your CSV file location, you can deploy and run your application as a normal command line tool.
3. As described in #2, your *importer* application will be deployed from your master node to all your workers. What matters here is where your CSV file is. A simple way to deploy it is by splitting the file across your worker nodes (using the same local file path), and load it as a local file. But be aware that you'd lose your local CSV part if the node dies. For more reliable distribution you can place your CSV file on an HDFS cluster then read from there.
4. Using Spark Cassandra Connector, you can load your data from Cassandra into RDDs on the corresponding local nodes, then using the RDDs you created by loading your CSV data, you can perform Joins and of course write the result back to Cassandra if you need to. You can use the Spark Cassandra Connector as a higher level tool to perform both the reading and writing, you wouldn't need to use the Java Driver directly (as the connector is built on top of it anyway).

Comment: Thanks for answer, maybe I was not clear, I need to load data from CSV to Cassandra, so for number 1. we need connector as well to save data to existing cassandra table from CSV after processing. And number 4 is completely independent of CSV import, there are tables which we currently join and sort on application level so I wanted to know will spark help with this as well

Comment: For #4 it's easy to use the connector to load the data into RDDs, then use Spark Joins on the RDDs http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/programming-guide.html#JoinLink ... For #1, I meant that you can use the Java Driver with a simple wrapper to handle local connections to Cassandra, but of course the connector would support out the box, that's why I said it's not really a significant help.

Comment: Only one thing regarding number #4 is not clear to me. My existing application is reading data from Cassandra on other server and exposing through rest API. Spark Cassandra connector along with join job must be deployed to Spark Cluster or we can use JOINS remotely (like some kind of RPC by creating SparkContext in existing application)?

Comment: Spark Cassandra Connector will only load the data directly from Cassandra. and if the Cassandra node is not running a Spark worker, then you won't benefit from data locality (as you'll end up streaming the data over the network to the spark workers). If you're loading the data through an API, then you won't be able to use the connector for reads.

Comment: Maybe I am unclear, lets say 3 database nodes can have workers, application server which is on 4th machine uses java driver and session to load data, process it on application level and exposes it through Rest API to outside world. I am searching for an option to remove application processing and move that to Spark Cluster and delegate to Spark workers. Can that be done from Application server on 4th machine?